# TypeError: google.maps.MarkerLabel is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to customize the color of the label of my marker with Google Maps V3, and searching on the documentation I've found that there's a class named google.maps.MarkerLabel.

Searching on the web I've found some explaes of usage and here's what I've tried to do:

```
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker ({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lon),
            map: map,
            id: data.id,
            type: data.type,
            type_description: data.type_description,
            name: data.name,
            via: data.via,      
            civico: data.civico,
            comune: data.comune,
            cap: data.cap,
            giorno: data.giorno,
            orario: data.orario,
            description: data.description,
            note: data.note,
            label: new google.maps.MarkerLabel({
                text: data.id,
                color: "white"
            }),
            icon: '<cms:link>../resources/images/' + data.markerIcon + '</cms:link>'                            
        });
```

The message tells me MarkerLabel is not a costructor. Ok, but where should I call it to make by object id (which is of course a number) coloured white?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

a [`google.maps.MarkerLabel`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerLabel) doesn't have a constructor, it is an anonymous object.

Use it like this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker ({
        position: map.getCenter(), 
        map: map,
        label: {
            text: "A", // data.id,
            color: "white"
        }                            
    });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/dwmb1cav/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(), // new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lon),
    map: map,
    label: {
      text: "A",
      color: "white"
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```